# winJS HtmlControl and Splitvew

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, winjs

I have a SplitView page. And in Navigation section I do like this:

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand" onclick="manager.selectUsers();" data-win-options="{
                    label:'Users',
                    icon:'people',
                }"></div>
```

where selectUsers() contains code:

```
 $("#content").empty();
        const htmlControl = new WinJS.UI.HtmlControl(document.getElementById("content"), { uri: `/manager/scopes` });
        WinJS.UI.processAll();
```

It navigates nice and neat. But I need to work with jquery and use DOM. I have a tag with "container". But my jquery can't see it probably because the page is not ready.

How to do it all, especially things related to the ready event for HtmlControl ?